# Erro no formulário, Falha ao carregar pagina

Tags: php, phpmailer

Quando aperto em ENVIAR, o submit envia para o /contato.php porem na pagina aparece:

A página de door.com.br não está a funcionar

door.com.br não consegue processar este pedido de momento.
HTTP ERROR 500

```
 <form method="post" action="contato.php">
                        <input type="text" name="nome" class="nome" id="NOME:" value="<?php
                           if(($_SESSION['incompleto'] == true) || ($_SESSION['erro'] == true)){
                            if($_SESSION['nome'] == true){
                             echo $_SESSION['nome'];
                              unset($_SESSION['nome']);
                             }
                             else{
                             echo 'NOME:';
                             }
                             }
                            else{
                            echo 'NOME:';
                             }?>" />
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="mail" id="E-MAIL:" value="<?php
                            if(($_SESSION['incompleto'] == true) || ($_SESSION['erro'] == true)){
                            if($_SESSION['email'] == true){
                              echo $_SESSION['email'];
                             unset($_SESSION['email']);
                              }
                            else{
                             echo 'E-MAIL:';
                             }
                            }
                            else{
                           echo 'E-MAIL:';
                          }?>" />
                        <input type="tel" name="tel" class="tel" id="TELEFONE:" value="<?php
                          if(($_SESSION['incompleto'] == true) || ($_SESSION['erro'] == true)){
                            if($_SESSION['tel'] == true){
                           echo $_SESSION['tel'];
                           unset($_SESSION['tel']);
                            }
                            else{
                             echo 'TELEFONE:';
                              }
                              }
                              else{
                              echo 'TELEFONE:';
                              }?>" />
                        <textarea name="mensagem" class="mensagem" id="DEIXE SUA MENSAGEM:"><?php
                          if(($_SESSION['incompleto'] == true) || ($_SESSION['erro'] == true)){
                           if($_SESSION['mensagem'] == true){
                           echo $_SESSION['mensagem'];
                            unset($_SESSION['mensagem']);
                            }
                             else{
                              echo 'DEIXE SUA MENSAGEM:';
                            }
                                unset($_SESSION['incompleto']);
                                unset($_SESSION['erro']);
                            }
                           else{
                            echo 'DEIXE SUA MENSAGEM:';
                             }?></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" />
                    </form>
```

contato.php

```
<?php

    session_start();
    ob_start();
    // envio de mensagem de contato para o e-mail

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefone = $_POST['tel'];
    $txt = $_POST['mensagem'];

    if(($nome != "") && ($email != "") && ($telefone != "") && ($txt != "") && ($nome != "NOME:") && ($email != "E-MAIL:") && ($telefone != "TELEFONE:") && ($txt != "DEIXE SUA MENSAGEM:")){
        // Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer

        require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

        // Inicia a classe PHPMailer

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        // Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão

        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

        $mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP

        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)

        $mail->Host     = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";

        $mail->Port     = 465;

        $mail->Username = 'teste@door.com.br'; // Username de acesso ao e-mail

        $mail->Password = '123'; // Senha do servidor SMTP

        // Define o remetente

        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

        $mail->From = "teste@door.com.br"; // Seu e-mail
        $mail->FromName = "Formulário de Contato DOOR Entretenimento"; // Seu nome

        // Define os destinatário(s)

        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
        $mail->AddAddress('teste@door.com.br');
        $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $nome);

        // Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem

        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

        $mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
        $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8'; // Charset da mensagem

         // Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
        $mail->Subject  = "Mensagem de Contato do Site DOOR"; // Assunto da mensagem
        $mail->Body = "<font style=\"font-size:15px\"><b>Nome:</b> $nome; <br /><b>E-mail:</b> $email; <br /><b>Telefone:</b> $telefone; <br /></font><br /><br /><h1>Mensagem: </h1><hr /><br /> <h2>{$txt}</h2>";
        $mail->AltBody = "Nome: $nome;\r\n E-mail: $email;\r\n Telefone: $telefone;\r\n \r\n Mensagem:  $txt \r\n ";

        // Envia o e-mail

        $enviado = $mail->Send();

        // Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        $mail->ClearAttachments();


        // Exibe uma mensagem de resultado

        if ($enviado) {
            $_SESSION['exito'] = true;
            header("Location: index.php");
        } 
        else {
            $_SESSION['erro'] = true;
            $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['tel'] = $telefone;
            $_SESSION['mensagem'] = $txt;
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['incompleto'] = true;
        if($_POST['nome'] != 'NOME:'){
            $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
        }
        if($_POST['email'] != 'E-MAIL:'){
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        }
        if($_POST['tel'] != 'TELEFONE:'){
            $_SESSION['tel'] = $telefone;
        }
        if($_POST['mensagem'] != 'DEIXE SUA MENSAGEM:'){
            $_SESSION['mensagem'] = $txt;
        }
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem um erro interno servidor. Provavelmente seu código tem erro de sintaxe/lógica/etc. Você pode olhar os logs do servidor onde a aplicação está rodando para ver em que parte está o erro. Ou você pode testar em um ambiente local e verificar em qual linha ou parte do código está o erro.

Comment: obrigado, estava dando um erro no servidor...